# SQL/R: Joining 2 tables such that the attribute values form 2nd table become attributes of the first

Tags: sql, r, join

When joining 2 tables, I want to transform record values as attributes. (i.e.  I have these two tables):

Customer table:

```
|CustomerId| Name|

|1         |Abc  |

|2         |Xyz  |
```

and I have Food preference table:

```
|CustomerId|Preference |

|1         |Continental|

|1         |Italian    |

|2         |Italian    |

|2         |Indian     |

|2         |Chinese    |
```

Now I want to join the 2 tables into the following table:

```
|CustomerId|Name|Food-Continental|Food-Italian|Food-Indian|Food-Chinese|

|1         |Abc |TRUE            |TRUE        |FALSE      |FALSE       |

|1         |Xyz |FALSE           |TRUE        |TRUE       |TRUE        |
```

Is there a script in R or an SQL query which will help me achieve this easily? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. For example, with this input

```
a<-read.table(text="CustomerId Name
  1 Abc
  2 Xyz", header=T)
b<-read.table(text="CustomerId Preference
  1 Continental
  1 Italian
  2 Italian
  2 Indian
  2 Chinese", header=T)
```

then you can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
inner_join(a, b) %>% mutate(val=TRUE) %>% 
    spread(Preference, val, fill=FALSE)
```

Which produces

```
  CustomerId Name Chinese Continental Indian Italian
1          1  Abc   FALSE        TRUE  FALSE    TRUE
2          2  Xyz    TRUE       FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
```

You can change the column names and order if you really want, but this should give you the data.

The transformation is done in two steps. First, we do a standard merge it the data. This results in a dataset in the "long" format. We then use `spread` to reshape the long data into wide format.

Answer (score 0):

I've got what you're asking for using **MSSQL**. Try it.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID,
    Name,
    CASE WHEN Continental='Continental' Then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Food-Continental],
    CASE WHEN Italian='Italian' Then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Food-Italian],
    CASE WHEN Indian='Indian' Then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END [Food-Indian],
    CASE WHEN Chinese='Chinese' Then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END [Food-Chinese]
    FROM (
SELECT 
     A.CustomerID,Name,Preference
FROM customer A 
     LEFT JOIN 
     food B on A.CustomerID=B.CustomerID) AS C

     PIVOT(
            MIN(Preference) FOR Preference IN ([Continental],[Italian],[Indian],[Chinese])
          )AS PVT
```